# chsh: Cannot determine your user name. while trying to setup zsh

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I have installed **oh-my-zsh** and now trying to make it my default shell. but when I trying to enter `chsh -s $(which zsh)` command it is giving me this --> **chsh: Cannot determine your user name.** error.

Please help me, guys.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that your system restricts the ability to change the shell.

You should contact your own uni tech support for instructions, or construct a dedicated shell **rc** file that runs **zsh** directly, depending on the `$SHELL` you have by default.

Here's a sample code which I had to use in my system.

```
if($?prompt) then
  exec /usr/bin/zsh -l
  export SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
endif
```